# Windows Photo Viewer Incorrect Colours with Multiple Displays

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, multiple-monitors, colors

I've got a multiple monitor setup and one of the monitors is a IPS 27" Dell I use for colour sensitive work. Windows has a colour profile associated with that monitor.

If I open a photo in Photoshop on the Dell monitor the colours look fine. However, if I open the same photo in Windows Photo Viewer all the colours are noticeably incorrect, mainly in the shadows. Some shadows appear completely black while in Photoshop you can clearly see tons of detail.

If I drag the Photoshop window and the Windows Photo Viewer on to one of my other monitors, which don't have a colour profile, then the colours look the same in both Photoshop and Windows Photo Viewer. However, with Photoshop when you drag the Photoshop window between monitors as you release the window on the new monitor you see the colours "snap" to the appropriate colours for that monitor. This does not occur with Windows Photo Viewer.

From my research I read that problems with colours in Windows Photo Viewer could be caused by incorrect profiles assigned to monitors. However, only the Dell has a colour profile associated and I can confirm that that profile is correct.

How can I get Windows Photo Viewer to display the correct colours?

Comment: [These](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/dacd4cf2-56cb-4089-8f2d-834420754a91/windows-photo-viewer-and-icc-profiles) two [threads](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=153209) might be useful to you.

Comment: @Karan It displays correctly if I embed my monitor's profile in the image but obviously this is not a practical or realistic solution. Also the only thing I can see in the second thread is the removal of the profile, but there is nothing wrong with my monitor's profile and I don't want to remove it.

Comment: In the first thread *michanagel* has mentioned what does and doesn't work with Photo Viewer. Unlikely you'll be able to make the program work in a different manner.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.  Installed the Dell driver for the monitor (In my case an S2340L) and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but because there are no Windows 8.1 drivers for my monitor (Dell 1907FP), I removed all color profiles (found in the Control Panel)

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).